# ACID database query

Tags: database, atomic, acid

A person is trying to transfer money from account a to account b. The most naive and natural single threaded implementation would be using a mutex for respecting atomicity and concurrency.

mutex.wait()
 a = a -50

b = b +50

mutex.signal()

I am sure this solution does not scale as number of mutex resources are limited and there would be several users of such systems.

What are the ways if any to make it a scalable solution ?

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: The question is "What are the other alternatives available as this problem surely must have been solved.?"

Comment: where is the "acid database query"?, your code is java (maybe), that problem HAVE BEEN SOLVED and is named TRANSACTION. When you use a transaction, dont care about scalability, that is db engine problem